# How to get `kubectl` to pipe mulitpage output to a pager?

Tags: bash, kubectl, pager

In `git` I can use:

```
git config --global core.pager "less -FX"
```

This will:

- When an output is longer (like `git log`) than a single page a pager (`less`) is used
- When output is short, it is not

Is there a configuration like this for `kubectl`?

Answer (score 3):

You could always wrap it in a function.

```
kubectl () {
    command kubectl "$@" |
    less --quit-if-one-screen
}
```

If you are happy with this solution, you can save it to your shell's interactive startup file.

A problem with the pipe to `less` is that it will mask the exit status of the actual `kubectl` command. In Bash, you could add `return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to the end of the function, before the closing brace.